# overloading operator-> for iterator where underlying container doesn't store real objects

Tags: c++, iterator, operator-overloading

I've a `diagonal` class which serves as principle diagonal. To minimize space I am storing `{begin: point, size: int}` instead of storing a list of `point`s

Now My algorithms will be easy to implement If I can make the diagonal iterable. So I wrote one `point_iterator`

```
class point_iterator{
  friend class diagonal;
  const diagonal& _diagonal;
  size_t    _position;
  public:
    typedef point_iterator self_type;
    typedef point value_type;
    typedef point reference;//< returning value instead of reference
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<point> pointer;//< it can never return pointer
    typedef std::random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;
    typedef boost::int32_t difference_type;
  public:
    pointer operator->(){return pointer(new point(_diagonal.at(_position)));}
    point operator*(){return _diagonal.at(_position);}
```

as there is no `point` stored anywhere in container I cannot return reference or pointer through my iterator. So in all cases I've to create a point (copyable) object and return.

So my reference typedef is actually not reference. Is this okay ?

I cannot implement `operator->()` which returns `point` object, it has to return some pointer, `point*` or pointer like. and I cannot just return `new point(operator*())` because  user will need to delete them. So I am using `shared_ptr` instead. Is this okay ?

I couldn't use `unique_ptr` because Its C++11. and `scoped_ptr` is not copyable.

Comment: Why not store a point in the iterator itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return an object storing a `point` and providing an overload of `operator->()`: The calls to `operator->()` are chained until it eventually gets to a result which does return a pointer:

```
class point_pointer
{
private:
    point m_p;
public:
    point_pointer(point p): m_p(p) {}
    pointer const* operator->() { return &this->m_p; }
};

point_pointer point_iterator::operator->() const {
    return point_pointer(this->operator*());
}
```

Although this approach would work, storing a `point` in the iterator is probably preferrable for performance reason and from an object life-time point of view.

Comment: You are writing one short of `scoped_ptr` which is copyable. similar to `unique_ptr`. Shouldn't I use/write a generic `copyable_scoped_ptr` for this ?

Comment: Note that the object "pointed to" is actually embedded inside the `point_pointer`. Clearly, this approach can be generalized but I don't think it is a `copyable_scoped_ptr`: The object gives a [partial] pointer-like feeling to an object.

Comment: @NeelBasu the difference is, in this case there is no heap allocation, no `new` or `delete` like a smart pointer would do, just a pointer to a stack allocated value object.